# Is there a Complete Psionic errata document?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, psionics

I heard there was one that was distributed *via* email, but I can't find a reference to it anywhere on the interwebs.

Does it exist, and, if it does, what does it cover?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I have never heard of this D: Much interest!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no official errata released for the Complete Psionic sourcebook. However, there is an unreleased version that [nijineko](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/30200/nijineko) got from a designer (you can read about it [here](http://minmaxforum.com/index.php?topic=344.msg34678#msg34678)). You can check the archive [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/dbmkg8efcbn4eak/AABVNzqrUl0ayi9QiyJTdbsLa/Nijineko_Archive/Complete_Psionic_Errata?dl=0&preview=Complete_Psionic_Errata_BRC0705.pdf).

Comment: It probably should be considered official, as it was actually submitted for publication by the author to WotC and approved, but due to some kerfuffles with the switchover to 4e, it was never actually put up on the website, sadly. The author kindly shared it with me, and I put it up as a public service, with permission. YMMV, and all that since it didn't make it onto the website in the end. Thanks for the mention. =D